# How to detect the src of an image inside an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I am accessing a database in WP. It returns an array. Inside are a few embedded HTML `<img>` tags. How can I search through the array to find the `src` of each `<img>`? and return it?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: use an html parser like `DOMDocument` or `simple-html-dom`

Answer (score 1):

Try starting from this

```
preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $wp_html, $img_src); 
print_r($img_src);
```